# How to change the color of the text in a Tabbed Panel Item when it is pressed down? (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

So I want to change the color of the text in a Tabbed Panel Item depending on whether it is pressed or not.

I know there is a function called "on_touch_down" and "on_release" but I'm not sure if they are the right ones to use or even how to use them.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the TabbedPanelItem's `state` is `down`

### Snippets

```
<TabbedPanelHeader>:
    background_normal: 'blue.png'
    background_down: 'red.png'
    color: (1, 1, 0, 1) if self.state == "down" else (1, 1, 1, 1)
```

## Output

[image: Tab1 - text colour changed]
[image: Tab2 - text colour changed]

Comment: Thanks a lot again!! btw where did you learn all this, I can't find any good references for this

Comment: Some from [Kivy TabbedPanel](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.html), and others through past experiences.